** IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your Python may not be configured for Tk. ** - is an error on Debian when running the command "sudo idle" in terminal
I am running Linux Debian and when I run the command sudo idle
in terminal, instead of giving me what it should, it just says this:
** IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your Python may not be configured for Tk. ** and then it goes back to being terminal.
I expected when I ran sudo idle that it would load me into a python editor with super-user privileges, but it just gave me that error message. Any ideas as to why it says what it says, and more importantly, how can I fix it? Would I be able to use the built-in python 3 for raspberry pi?

Note: it is a bad idea to run a idle as super user. Program with your user, and run as super user when the program is complete AND tested.

tk is typically packages as separate package at least on deb/ubuntu side of linux: python3-tk

Does this answer your question? Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?

sudo apt install idle3 then type  idle in terminal

@toyotaSupra sorry, I tried that already. It said there was an error. tomorrow i'll retrieve the error message for you.

You need to do sudo apt update first

@toyotaSupra I tried that, and it saidit failed to unpack the packages

Here is link: https://vitux.com/how-to-install-idle-python-ide-on-debian-10/

@toyotaSupra it fails on the update. It said it failed to get the packages to update. Could it be my WiFi?

must be firewall. Does your internet working or not? What is your OS platform?

@toyotaSupra I have pretty poor internet. I am running Linux Debian 10 as a Raspberrry pi 3.

OIC. That is biggest problem. I used RPI 2-5 using Bullseye and Bookworm. You could go to library or perhaps your friend(s).

@toyotaSupra thanks, I really appriciate your help. (I'm not being sarcastic, I promise.)

I usually help to solve problem.
